# POSTFIX: New mail server. Can neither send nor receive mail

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to learn about mail servers and have setup one. However neither can I send, nor receive mail.
I can login to my email account and I see the folders (Inbox, Sent, Trash, etc) are being populated within the email client.
Also /var/log/syslog indicates that my user has successfully logged in via imap-login

When I click on the test button from Thunderbird before logging in, the test always fails with: "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account"
I have turned off the firewall on the server completely. My DNS records I believe are properlly set up as an MX lookup returns no errors/warnings.
I have verified the mysql user specified within dovecot does have permissions over the database used for mail, the domain, alias and accounts tables have all been created.
hostmaster@mydomain.abc has been imported into the accounts table.

Any ideas?

This is [the guide](https://thomas-leister.de/en/mailserver-debian-stretch/) I followed to set it up and I am as well using Debian 9.
Thanks!

Comment: You entered a domain that doesn't exist. What is the real domain name?

Comment: @anx, apologies which are the logs you are referring to? Is there some sort of thunderbird log or do you want me to pull out something from the OS? Also do you want me to login/run a test/try to send mail or receive before I provide the logs?
Sorry as I said I'm new to mail. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to enter the settings yourself. Thunderbird doesn't actually autodetect anything; it just consults a database of major email providers. It looks like you've done that already, so you should move on to checking the mail server logs.

Comment: Hi, sorry it's late.. so I did the below actions and have provided an output of tail -30 /var/log/syslog over here: https://pastebin.com/efkaPxMp 
Let me know if this isn't what you guys were referring to. Thanks

- ran the thunderbird test (failed)
- logged in via thunderbird (successful)
- sent mail to my gmail (failed)
- sent mail from my gmail (failed)

Comment: Yes, and you should also read the logs yourself. The problem became obvious: `Jul 31 00:58:02 mail postfix/smtpd[2482]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Access denied for user 'vmail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: I am assuming somewhere I have configured a restriction as to which domains my mail server can send mail.. just not sure where this setting may be

Comment: OK, so I am trying to send mail to gmail.com. I can ping their mail server and I can also do telnet on :25 to it. However I can't do telnet on 587 to it and this is what my mail server is set to use. Can this be the reason?
`root@mail:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 142.250.102.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.`
...
`root@mail:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 587
Trying 142.250.102.26...
Trying 2a00:1450:4025:402::1a...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Port 587 is for *submission* alone and should not be used for SMTP between MTAs.

Comment: Hi Thank you all for the support. As the issue now is different from what it was initially I shall create a new post specific to why postfix isn't sending mail, referencing my smtpd restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the /var/sys/syslog there were mysql access denied errors for the postfix db.
One of the files within /etc/postfix/sql/ had a typo in the postfix password.

I can now receive mail without issues, however outgoing mail doesn't work.
As the issue now differs from it initially was I am answering this so a new post can be created more specific to the current failures.